# Cygwin on Windows 7 (64bit): No such file or directory - but 'which' does give me the correct path

Tags: bash, windows-7, cygwin

A formely working bash script no longer works after switching computers. I get the following error:
No such file or directory.

Before going on, please excuse any mistakes you may find since english is not my native language.

The script was used in cygwin under Windows XP. I now had to switch to cygwin64 under Windwos 7 (64bit).
The script is used as a checkhandler for the program SMSTools3 to split a file with a specific format into multiple smaller ones, which the program then uses to send SMS to multiple recipients. The script was copied directly from the page of SMSTools3 and uses the package formail.

After looking up the error the most likely problem was that the environmantle path was not set up to look in the right path (/usr/bin). I therefore added it to the path but to no avail.
I then deleted other entries in the enviromental path of windows which contained spaces because that could have been another explanation, but again to no avail.

Following is a minimal example of the code which produces the error.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Sample script to allow multiple recipients in one message file.
# Define this script as a checkhandler.

echo $PATH
which formail

outgoing="/var/spool/sms/outgoing"

recipients=`formail -zx "To:" < "$1"`
```

I added the lines the lines `echo $Path` and `which formail` to show if the script can find the correct file. Both results look fine, the second command gives me the right output '/usr/bin/formail'

But the line `recipients=...` throws me the error:
No such file or directory.

I do not have much experience with bash scripting, or cygwin in general. So if someone on this wonderful board could help me solve this problem, I would be really grateful. Thank you all for your help.

EDIT: 
First of all thank you all for your comments.

Secondly, I would like to apologize for the late reply. The computer in question is also used for other purposes and my problem is part of a background routine, so  I have to wait for "free time" on the pc to test things.

For the things @shellter pruposed: The ls command returned an error: '': No such file or directory.

The which -a formail as well as the echo $(which -a formail) commands that @DougHenderson pruposed returned the 'right' path of /usr/bin/formail. echo \$1 = $1 before the recipent line returned the path to the checkhandler file (/usr/local/bin/smsd_checkhandler.sh), the same command after the recipent line seems to show a empty string ($1 = ). Also, the pruposed change to the recipent line did not change the error.

For the dos2unix conversion that @DennisWilliamson pruposed, I opened the file in notepad++ to use their build in converion, but it showed me that the file is in unix format with Unix style line endings.

Comment: Add an `ls -l "$1"` as part of your debugging. If `which` can find `formail` then it must be something else, right? ;-).. Your english is better (written) than a lot of native speakers I know, keep posting!

Comment: Try `which -a formail` and `echo $(which -a formail)`. Consider using `recipients=$(formail -zx "To:" < "$1")` which should give identical results, but may have subtle differences when bash parses the command. Also add a `echo \$1 = $1` to be sure the value is correct, and check if there are spaces in that file name.

Comment: One strong possibility is that there are Windows line endings in the file. Try removing them using `dos2unix` or similar and make sure you save scripts using Linux/Unix line endings.

Comment: @shellter: Thank you for your answer. The ls command returned an error: '': No such file or directory. The cygwin terminal is open in the path /usr/bin and the file is in the path /usr/local/bin if that is important.

Comment: @DougHenderson First of all thank you. The which lines still give the correct path and the change toi the recipent line did not help. The output of the echo \$1 = $1 seems to be an empty string after the error line.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thank you for your help. It seems that the file is already in unix format, atleast notepad++ tells me so.

Comment: Since `echo "$1"` shows an empty string, that is the source of your error. Are you passing an argument to the script when you run it?

Comment: I just noticed you said `ls` returned `command not found`. That's not right. That is one of the most basic commands of all *nixdom! ;-). What does `echo "PATH=XX${PATH}ZZ"` show? (DId you get a solution, or are you still trying to get this to work?). Good luck.

Comment: To let readers know you are mentioning them in comments, be sure to use the for @NikUOS ;-)